# Pass an object to a function without copying it on change

Tags: r, memory-management

#### My question

If an object `x` is passed to a function `f` that modifies it R will create a modified local copy of `x` within `f`'s environment, rather than changing the original object (due to the copy-on-change principle). However, I have a situation where `x` is very big and not needed once it has been passed to `f`, so I want to avoid storing the original copy of `x` once `f` is called. Is there a clever way to achieve this?

`f` is an unknown function to be supplied by a possibly not very clever user.

#### My current solution

The best I have so far is to wrap `x` in a function `forget` that makes a new local reference to `x` called `y`, removes the original reference in the workspace, and then passes on the new reference. The problem is that I am not certain it accomplish what I want and it only works in `globalenv()`, which is a deal breaker in my current case.

```
forget <- function(x){
    y <- x
    # x and y now refers to the same object, which has not yet been copied
    print(tracemem(y))
    rm(list=deparse(substitute(x)), envir=globalenv())
    # The outside reference is now removed so modifying `y`
    # should no longer result in a copy (other than the
    # intermediate copy produced in the assigment)
    y
}

f <- function(x){
    print(tracemem(x))
    x[2] <- 9000.1
    x
}
```

Here is an example of calling the above function.

```
> a <- 1:3
> tracemem(a)
[1] "<0x2ac1028>"
> b <- f(forget(a))
[1] "<0x2ac1028>"
[1] "<0x2ac1028>"
tracemem[0x2ac1028 -> 0x2ac1e78]: f 
tracemem[0x2ac1e78 -> 0x308f7a0]: f 
> tracemem(b)
[1] "<0x308f7a0>"
> b
[1]    1.0 9000.1    3.0
> a
Error: object 'a' not found
```

#### Bottom line

Am I doing what I hope I am doing and is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's some sort of `rm(x,.GlobalEnv)` thing, as many `R` tools let you specify the environment in which to execute the command.  But let me ask: if `x` is only used inside your function, why did you load it into your workspace in the first place?  Why not create or load `x` from inside the function?

Comment: You are rigth, some background might be called for. I have a dataset that I repeatedly want to extract two random subsets from: a design set `x` and a test set `y`. Based on the design set I want to define a transform to be applied to both sets. I then want to send the designset `x` into a model fitting function `f` supplied by the user to obtain a model `m`. I then want to apply `m` to `y` and calculate performance. As `f` can be memory intensive and `x` is large I figured it would help to discard whatever I don't need before calling `f`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**(1) Environments** You can use environments for that:

```
e <- new.env()
e$x <- 1:3
f <- function(e) with(e, x <- x + 1)
f(e)
e$x
```

**(2) Reference Classes** or since reference classes automatically use environments use those:

```
E <- setRefClass("E", fields = "x",
    methods = list(
        f = function() x <<- x + 1
    )
)
e <- E$new(x = 1:3)
e$f()
e$x
```

**(3) proto objects** also use environments:

```
library(proto)
p <- proto(x = 1:3, f = function(.) with(., x <- x + 1))
p$f()
p$x
```

ADDED: proto solution

UPDATED: Changed function name to `f` for consistency with question.

Comment: The environment function should be able to do what I am looking for. Do I get it right that my unknown function `f` would be the same as your function `myfun`, requiring the user supplying `f` to always wrap the function body in a call to `with`? It's a bit unpretty but if it gets the job done the user will have to accept that.

Comment: @Backlin, Have changed function name to `f` for consistency with question.  In (1)  Environments either wrap body in `with` as shown or refer to components in the environment as `e$x` so that `f <- function(e) e$x <- e$x + 1` works too.  In (2) Reference Classes  just refer to the variables in the environment directly as shown and can use <<- to set them. `.self$x` also works. In (3) proto the situation is the same as plain environments; however, if you never make use of inherited methods (e.g. the example above does not use them) then the same approach as in reference classes will work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest approach is to only load the working copy into memory, instead of loading both the original (global namespace) and the working copy (function namespace).  You can sidestep your whole issue by using the 'ff' package to define your 'x' and 'y' data sets as 'ffdf' data frames.  As I understand it, 'ffdf' data frames reside on disk and load into memory only as parts of the data frame are needed and purge when those parts are no longer necessary.  This would mean, theoretically, that the data would be loaded into memory to copy into the function namespace and then purged after the copy was complete.

I'll admit that I rarely have to use the 'ff' package, and when I do, I usually don't have any issues at all.  I'm not checking specific memory usage, though, and my goal is usually just to perform a large calculation across the data.  It works, and I don't ask questions.