# Memory efficient way to modify a variable within a function

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, global

**Problem**

I want to write a function that modifies each column of a big matrix, *x*:

```
f = function(x){
    # do something to x
    # return x
}
```

Because *x* is very large, I would like to modify it "in place", i.e. without creating a copy. However, my understanding is that in R, functions are "copy on modify." In other words, if I modify *x* within the function *f*, R will make a copy of *x*.

**Proposed solution (*Update: Does not work! See answers below for details.*)**

Therefore, it seems that the best solution is to modify the global variable, i.e.

```
f = function(x){
    x = deparse(substitute(x))
    x = get(x, envir = globalenv())
    # do something to x
}
```

**Question**

However, people on SO are VERY negative about passing global variables into functions in R. Some people have even been downvoted simply for asking about it.

My question is: what is the best way to do something like this within R?

Comment: I’m pretty sure your proposed solution will still create a copy inside f, but I’d be curious to test it.

Comment: The `data.table` package. Assignments inside regular R functions still make an intermediate *temp* copy. The only way to avoid that is to redefine [<- as Matt Dowle did.

Comment: I am curious which questions were down-voted for *"passing global variables into functions"* ... it's unavoidable in all but the most strictest environment. The contrary I can believe: accessing (even modifying) global variables from within a function, without being passed, by breaching lexical scope. There are times where a purely functional method might be inefficient, but uncontrolled side-effect makes debugging and code maintenance extremely difficult. Unfortunately, as @42- suggested, R is almost completely about ref-by-copy and copy-on-write, `data.table` being a notable exception.

Comment: `data.table` would be helpful in this case. For example: modify in place of chosen columns `cols <- names(dt)[c(1, 5, 10)];
dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x/mean(x)), .SDcols = cols]`

Comment: @Tung, in your solution, I am curious how much memory is used? My understanding is that data.table create two objects in memory (the original data table and the mean-scaled table), then replaces one with the other? Or is each column in the original table replaced immediately after its new mean-centered value is calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was already discussed here:

[Pass an object to a function without copying it on change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647636/pass-an-object-to-a-function-without-copying-it-on-change?rq=1)

Your second approach does not really solve the problem. Here is the test I ran with the results of mem_used()

```
library(pryr)
mem_used()
#41.3 MB

x <- matrix(1:1000000000, ncol=1000)
mem_used()
#4.04GB


f2<- function(x){
  print(mem_used())
  x = deparse(substitute(x))
  print(mem_used())
  x = get(x, envir = globalenv())
  x<- x+1
  print(mem_used())
  x
}

x <- f2(x)
#4.04 GB
#4.04 GB
#12 GB
mem_used()
#8.04GB
```

Comment: Good to know. I will update my question to reflect this. Thanks!